# Do singularities in real algebraic varieties have measure zero?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

This question is related to [Do proper Zariski closed sets of algebraic sets have measure zero](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138057/do-proper-zariski-closed-sets-of-algebraic-sets-have-measure-zero)

For algebraic varieties on complex numbers, it is easy to see that the locus of their singularies are set of zero measure, since any proper closed subset in Zariski topology has zero measure. This argument is possible since open sets in Zariski topology are dense.

For real algebraic varieties, it is not possible to use Zariski topology.

How to prove that singularities in real algebraic varieties have measure zero.

Comment: What about $x^2+y^2=0$ in $R^2$? The real locus is just the singular point, which has full measure inside itself (though its 1-d Hausdorff measure is still zero).

Comment: Thanks for this nice counter-example. I wonder if is it possible to find a counter-example with a dimension higher than 1.  @Jonny Evans

Comment: The same example works in any dimension, adding more squared variables to the quadratic (in all cases the real locus is just one point).

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ is a real algebraic variety with 0 dimensions embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The aim of my question was if it is possible to find a real algebraic variety with a dimension higher than 0 in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that its singularities have a non-zero measure.

Comment: I think x^2+y^2=0 in the plane has dimension 1 by any reasonable notion of dimension, it's just that you can't compute dimension by looking at points in the singular locus and the are no other real points. If you want your singular locus to have higher dimension, you can multiply this example by extra copies of R and not change the quadratic form to get a variety consisting entirely of singular points.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is a variety of complex dimension n whose real locus contains an n dimensional space of singularities? If your variety is reduced, I don't think this can happen because the Zariski closure of the real locus is everything, so you would end up with an n dimensional complex singular locus.

Comment: If you allow non-reduced then x^2=0 in R is a counterexample.

Comment: Or $x^2+y^2=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2+n}$ has real points $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are all singular points. Also what do you mean by measure? There could be multiple real components which could have different real dimension. Should the measure depend on the local dimension or the max of the dimensions?